# What's the best way to get notification of Docker Failures with GCP Compute Engine `create-with-container`

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to be notified of a failure of a docker container on a container optimized VM on GCP?

I suppose we could use a Logging sink and parse the messages there, but is there a better method?

Specifically I'm running `gcloud compute instances create-with-container $NAME...`

Thanks!